# Equation system with two unknown variables $xy=6930$ and $y/x=1.41$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am sorry if this is too easy for you, but it's been very many decades since I had math at school. ;-) Please also consider that English is a foreign language for me.

I need to resolve X and Y for this equation system:

\begin{align}
x\cdot y &= 6930\\
\frac yx &= 1.41
\end{align}

How can this be done and which are the steps to the solution? Please write in easy to understand arithmetic language (no advanced mathematical symbols please).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment on the offchance that $1.41$ is an "engineering approximation" for $\sqrt{2}$ but exercising that approximation too soon loses a full significant digit: $\sqrt{\frac{6930}{1.41}} \simeq 70.106$ vs. $\sqrt{\frac{6930}{\sqrt{2}}} \simeq 70.001$.

Comment: Thanks, 1.41 in my specific case is a "good enough" approximation for the calculation of a rectangle model where starting from the aspect ratio of the edges of a DIN page (1.41) the edges of the rectangle change and the area of the rectangle must remain the same (6930). The solution I received here helped me to achieve this.

Comment: BTW, there is an error in the changed title: The second equation is not "x/y = 1.41" but "y/x = 1.41". Sorry, I don't know how the mathematical formatting is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equation
$$
x \cdot y = 6930 \quad (*)
$$
implies that both $x$ and $y$ can not be zero.

So the second equation
$$
\frac{y}{x} = 1.41 \quad (**)
$$
is equivalent (has the same solutions) to 
$$
y = 1.41 \cdot x
$$
We can insert this into the first equation and get
$$
x \cdot (1.41 \cdot x) = 6930
$$
which simplifies to
$$
x^2 = \frac{6930}{1.41}
$$
or 
$$
x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{6930}{1.41}}
$$
where the $\pm$ is short hand notation for two solutions, one positive, one negative.

Finally we get
$$
y 
= 1.41 \cdot x 
= 1.41 \cdot \pm \sqrt{\frac{6930}{1.41}}
= \pm \sqrt{1.41 \cdot 6930}
$$
So we got four solutions in total, however equation $(*)$ or $(**)$ will only permit pairs of same signs, as we need a positive product or fraction, so we end up with two solutions:
$$
(x, y) = 
\pm \left( \sqrt{\frac{6930}{1.41}}, \sqrt{1.41 \cdot 6930}\right)
$$

**Update:**

Here you can fiddle with GeoGebra: [link](https://ggbm.at/hxugY3FE)

This free software allows you to solve the problem graphically, symbolic and numeric.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everybody, you helped me a lot! Now I understand the problem better.

Comment: BTW, is there a (free) software program (Windows 7) where I can put in these two equations in text form and it solves it?

Comment: @user1580348: You can use the Wolfram Alpha website: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy+%3D+6930,+y%2Fx+%3D+1.41

Comment: @user1580348 Would second Adreas' recommendation of Wolfram Alpha, however if you're specifically looking for local software (that works offline) I can recommend the "Equation Solver" feature of Microsoft Mathematics (Availible here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15702)

Comment: Thanks again to everybody! It is wonderful that there is a community where knowledge can be shared! Hopefully one day I can share some bit of knowledge too!

Comment: I added a link to a GeoGebra work sheet. It allows to solve the problem graphically, just enter the equations and try the intersect tool Or you can enter it in a CAS (Computer Algebra System) window and solve it symbolically or numerically.

Comment: Thank you, this looks really beautiful! I think I start to like Mathematics!

Answer (score 4):

If $y/x = 1.41$, then $y = 1.41x$. So plugging this in the first equation yields $1.41x^2 = 6930$ and thus $x = \pm \sqrt{6930/1.41}$. Now it should be easy to find also $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with$$\begin{align*} & xy=6930\tag1\\ & \tfrac yx=1.41\tag2\end{align*}$$
Multiplying the numerator and denominator of $(2)$ by $y$ gives$$\begin{align*} & \dfrac {y^2}{xy}=1.41\tag3\\ & y^2=1.41\cdot xy\tag4\\ & y^2=1.41\cdot 6930\tag5\\ & y=\pm\sqrt{9771.3}\end{align*}$$
Substitute that back into $(1)$ to get the corresponding $x$ values.

Answer (score 2):

First divide the first equation by X:

$$Y = 6930/X$$

Then substitute the Y into the 2nd equation.

$$(6930/X)/X=1.41$$

Multiply by X:

$$6930/X = 1.41X$$

... again

$$6930=1.41X^2$$

Divide by 1.41

$$4914.89=X^2$$

Take square root:

$$X= +/-70.10$$

Solve the Y by yourself :).